# Flutter pan/zoom via gesture or function

Tags: flutter, zooming, gesture, pan

My goal is to have a container of some sort, that I can zoom and pan via gestures, but also need to be able to zoom and pan to a specific location in the container via a button.  I've tried all sorts of combinations of GestureDetector's mixed with Matrix4Transform and MatrixGestureDetector but am not having any luck allowing both hand and function initiated gestures to work together.  Does anyone have something like this already working, and if so could you share any hints?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this package: [photo_view](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view).

Comment: Yes I've tried that one, however because you can only feed an image into it as opposed to a container or other widget, it doesn't fit my needs

Comment: I've missed the "container" part, my bad. However I've also found [zoom_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/zoom_widget#-readme-tab-). But I'm not sure about the zoom to a specific location via button.

Comment: @a344254 You can pass any widget to photoview with custom child: https://pub.dev/documentation/photo_view/latest/photo_view/PhotoView/PhotoView.customChild.html